# As a freelancer, how do I calculate my cost to company value?

Tags: resume

I am a VBA developer and Excel Automation developer.  I have developed lot of projects for some BPO companies for automating their process.  They settled their payments to my account directly but not from their company account.

Now, I am searching for new job and they are asking about my current cost to company. What value should I supply as a freelancer? I have all the income proof in my bank statement.

Comment: What is CTC? And what are Lakhs (ok.. Google indicates rupees??)? Stack Exchange, as a whole, assumes English/US first. If you have a question about some other country it is often helpful to designate *which* country in the question itself, or at least in the tags.

Comment: Sorry, but we're not accountants or attorneys here.  You'd be best contacting a professional in India who specializes in what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd use your income from the previous jobs as the ctc (cost to company) and just tell them you're a freelancer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just using your income amount instead.

Usually, the CTC (cost to company) also includes additional expenses on top of your salary that your company pays. Since the CTC is the entire cost that the company spends on you every month, your freelancing income should be about the same, since you'd probably need to pay those expenses yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am a freelancer from India who had a similar problem a while back. 
All you need to do is contact your client and ask them for an affidavit of payments made to you; the majority of companies here are happy with that as proof of income instead of payslips.

Your CTC would be equal to your income - as that is exactly how much your client spent to hire you.